# Is there an R function to write raster as float Geotiff with colormap?

Tags: r, raster, colormap, geotiff

I tried solution from answers to this question [Write classified raster with its symbology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427787/write-classified-raster-with-its-symbology?rq=1)
I used function
writeGDAL(r, outRstName, type="Byte" etc.)
but it only works with type "Byte", which include only integers from 0 to 256.

Is there solution for floats? I want to use it for data like air temperature maps. I save it with writeraster(format="GTiff") and it works well with floats.
I want to add color palette to have it with color for use in Arcgis.

Many thanks in advance,

Anastasiia.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. You can only store a color table with Byte or short integer values --- it is a restriction of the GeoTIFF file format. An ArcGIS color palette is a different thing altogether, I think.