# Writing categorial rasters with color and attribute symbology info in r

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I am generating landscape classification output rasters and adapted the code from WAF’s answer to the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427787/write-classified-raster-with-its-symbology) to generate geotifs with embedded standardized color and attribute information.

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

addColorTable <- function(inRstName, outRstName, rat.df){
  r<- readGDAL(inRstName)
  rat.df$color<- as.character(rat.df$color)
  rat.df$attribute<- as.character(rat.df$attribute)
  outRst <- writeGDAL(r, outRstName, type="Byte", 
                      colorTable=list(rat.df$color), 
                      catNames=list(rat.df$attribute), mvFlag=11L)
  return(raster(outRst))
}

# create dummy data set
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r[] <- 0
r[51:100] <- 1
r[3:6, 1:5] <- 2
r[1, 1] <- 3
writeRaster(r,'dummy_raster.tif',overwrite=T)

#create color and attribute table
# This defines the values, the color and the attribute
valT <- c(0,1,2,3)
colT <-  c("#FF0000", "#FF9900" ,"#99FF00","#0000FF")
attT <- c('Forest','Water body','City','Cropland')
rat.df <- data.frame(value=valT,color=colT,attribute=attT)

# apply the magic function
rnew <- addColorTable('dummy_raster.tif', 'dummy_raster_with_symbology.tif', rat.df)

plot(rnew)
```

[image]

The code works perfectly within r to generate the categorical land cover rasters with the proper colors (see figure above). However, no matter what I do, when I visualize the raster outside of r (e.g., qgis or arcgis) the raster legend includes legend elements for 0-255 raster values, even if my raster only has values between 0 and 3 (see figure below). This is not a huge deal but makes sharing these outputs with collaborators a bit limiting as the raster attributes appear broken. Does anyone have any solutions to correctly save raster color and attribute info in r?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This should work better with `terra`.

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r[] <- 0
r[51:100] <- 1
r[3:6, 1:5] <- 2
r[1, 1] <- 3

coltab(r) <- c("#FF0000", "#FF9900" ,"#99FF00","#0000FF")
levels(r) <- data.frame(id=0:3, cover=c('Forest','Water body','City','Cropland'))
x <- writeRaster(r, "test.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
plot(x)
```

[image]